# Site graduated! New design launched

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1281/design-for-expressionengine-stackexchange).

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the follow urls and do a hard browser refresh.

http://cdn.sstatic.net/expressionengine/img/favicon.ico

http://cdn.sstatic.net/expressionenginemeta/img/favicon.ico

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug."

We have also updated site's [Twitter](https://twitter.com/stackexpression) profile theme.
Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community!

Comment: Thanks, Stéphane! Looks great!

Comment: Oooh! How swanky!

Answer (score 8):

What a great accomplishment for the ExpressionEngine community! We wanted a place for free community support and so we built it together. There is nothing like manifesting your own destiny.

Thank you Stéphane for your beautiful design & Anna for your help getting us to this graduation!